# memoization based on function expression?

Tags: memoization

I want to create a function $f$ which takes as a parameter a function $h$, and calculates its integral between $a$ and $b$.

But I want to apply memoization to this, by only calculating the integral the first time it is called *for a particular function of $h$*.

If we have a normal function that takes a real number (instead of another function), then we simply do:

```
g[x_]:=g[x]=...
```

**How do we do this memoization for $f$, where the argument is the expression for a function?**

Comment: Have you tried doing it the same way?

Comment: @JohnDoty, honestly no, because I'm still confused as to how mathematica works internally, and I'm not how to even pass a function-expression, or how mathematica knows that I'm trying to pass the expression instead of the value.

Answer (score 3):

As a pure function:

```
f1[h_, a_, b_] := f1[h, a, b] = Integrate[h[x], {x, a, b}]
f1[#^2 &, 1, 2]
```

As a function of `x`:

```
f2[h_, a_, b_] := f2[h, a, b] = Integrate[h, {x, a, b}]
f2[x^2, 1, 2]
```

As a function of any variable `var`:

```
f3[h_, var_, a_, b_] := f3[h, var, a, b] = Integrate[h, {var, a, b}]
f3[y^2, y, 1, 2]
```

All give

> 7/3

Answer (score 1):

Implicitly, this works best if you express $h$ as a pure function, but it's relatively straightforwards. If you are interested in evaluating the integral from $a$ to $b$ precisely once, then this should work:

```
f[h_] := f[h] = Function[{a,b},Evaluate[Integrate[h[x],{x,a,b}]]];
```

This defines `f` as a function which takes a parameter `h` (which will need to be a function itself to work properly), and then memoizes its result. Its result is a function representing the evaluated integral of `h[x]`, to within Mathematica's abilities.

For example, `f[Sin]` (note that this is **not** `f[Sin[x]]`) will return:

```
Function[{a$,b$}, Cos[a$] - Cos[b$]]
```

This represents a function of `a$` and `b$` and contains the evaluated integral of `Sin`. From here `f[Sin][1,3]` will equal `Cos[1]-Cos[3]`, which is equal to `Integrate[Sin[x],{x,1,3}]`.

To evaluate a more arbitrary function, using pure functions is prudent. For example, to find the integral of $x^2$ once, write it as a pure function:

```
f[#^2 &]
(* Function[{a$,b$},-a$^3/3+b$^3/3] *)

f[#^2 &][1,2]
(* 7/3 *)
```

Comment: Thank you. I am wondering, why doesn't it work to simply do: f[h_] := (Integrate[h[x], {x, a, b}])[0, 1];
h[x_] := x^2;
f[h]? If I do this, it still returns the function, instead of the evaluation of the integral between 0 and 1.

Comment: @Programmer2134: You've dropped the `Function` declaration there, so you simply have some integral with a `[0,1]` attached to the end of it. Mathematica interprets that the same way it interprets `3[4]`. If you want it to be specifically between 0 and 1, then you could do something like: `f[h_] := f[h] = Integrate[h[x],{x,0,1}]`, and there's no need to return a function which accepts input.

Comment: Yet if I write >f[h_] := Function[{a, b}, Evaluate[Integrate[h[x], {x, a, b}]]][0, 1]; then it still gives me a function output. It's not that I need to write it like that necessarily, I am just still confused by how mathematica works inside, as it seems to me that this should simply output the number...

Comment: @Programmer2134 using that code exactly and entering `f[Sin]` I get `1-Cos[1]`, which seems to be the intended output. Are you using a pure function as the input (i.e. a function referenced by name without an input value, or an anonymous function like `#^2&` without a `[x]` attached to it)?

Comment: Yes I did, however, when I added "ClearAll[h,f]" in front of the code, it suddenly worked. I should get in the habbit of always doing that. The fact that mathematica "remembers" earlier, already removed definitions of symbols, seems to be a source of bugs for me. Thanks for the help!